# The constructor being called isn't

Tags: flutter, dart, default-constructor

I have a class which I intend to use in another class a default parameter.

```dart
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

/// Service to handle requesting of permissions.
/// Using extension methods disables testing
class PermissionService {
  /// Check the status of a specific [Permission]
  Future<PermissionStatus> status(Permission permission) {
    return permission.status;
  }

  /// Open the app settings.
  Future<bool> openAppSettings() {
    return openAppSettings();
  }

  /// Request permissions for a single permission.
  Future<PermissionStatus> request(Permission permission) {
    return permission.request();
  }
}
```

But I am getting this error below.

```dart
const permissionService = PermissionService(); 
// The constructor being called isn't a const constructor.
// Try removing 'const' from the constructor invocation.
```

Why can't I create the class as a const?

Answer (score 1):

Just like the error message tells you, `PermissionService` doesn't have a `const` constructor. Add one like this:

```
class PermissionService {
  Future<PermissionStatus> status(Permission permission) {
    return permission.status;
  }

  Future<bool> openAppSettings() {
    return openAppSettings();
  }

  Future<PermissionStatus> request(Permission permission) {
    return permission.request();
  }

  const PermissionService();
}
```

[docs](https://dart.dev/tools/diagnostic-messages#const_with_non_const)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I didn't know that without a constructor, a class cannot become a const

Answer (score 0):

If a class does not explicitly provide any constructors, the implicit default constructor is not automatically `const`.

The author of the class must make a conscious and explicit decision to provide a `const` constructor because changing the constructor from `const` to non-`const` later would be a breaking API change.

Comment: Aaah didn't notice that. Thanks for the info